# JSon parsing on listview in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

hi this is link to my project and web API files [My Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ocssjwzjyvzy2lt/Android%20Project%20%2B%20asp.net%20files.rar?dl=0)  i'm having few errors i'm using Android Studio. i want server data in listview on Android App[image: Errors Pic] kindly guide me thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to post what errors you're getting, what your JSON format is, etc.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<jarr> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<jarr>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

Comment: in above line i'm getting error at items

Comment: Yes but what is the error?

Comment: my json format is {"Order:"[{PID,PTitle,Quantity,Price}]}

Comment: What is the error you're getting?!?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you haven't got any variable like "items".

You have to first parse a json, and then set an adapter.

And your code is containing a lot of errors. For example:

It should be:

```
Order order = new Order(PID,....);
```